# useState is not updating state variable in async function

Tags: node.js, reactjs

```
const getChoices = async () => {
    try {
      setIsLoading(true);
      for (let i = 0; i < 1387; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < days.length; j++) {
          if (
            moment(data[i].date.start).utc().format("MM/DD/YYYY") === days[j]
          ) {
            const kli = await Contract.methods
              .GetChoice(data[i].id)
              .call({ from: Account[0] });
            console.log(kli);
            if (kli === "0") {
              // console.log(data[i]);
            } else {
              if (parseInt(kli) === data[i].teams.home.id) {
                console.log("inserted in home");
                console.log(data[i].id, data[i].teams.home.nickname);
                setChoices((oldState) => [
                  ...oldState,
                  {
                    MatchID: data[i].id,
                    BetTeamName: data[i].teams.home.nickname,
                  },
                ]);
              } else if (parseInt(kli) === data[i].teams.visitors.id) {
                console.log("inserted in vistiroes");
                setChoices((oldState) => [
                  ...oldState,
                  {
                    MatchID: data[i].id,
                    BetTeamName: data[i].teams.visitors.nickname,
                  },
                ]);
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
      console.log(choices[1]);
      setChoices([...new Set(choices)]);
      console.log(choices[0]);
    } finally {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  };
```

here is the async function which is used to append choices of each user.
it is called in useEffect. useState is not updating the state of variable.

here is console log

```
10PublicPools.js:56 0
PublicPools.js:56 25
PublicPools.js:71 inserted in vistiroes
PublicPools.js:56 26
PublicPools.js:61 inserted in home
PublicPools.js:62 11027 'Magic'
PublicPools.js:56 21
PublicPools.js:71 inserted in vistiroes
10PublicPools.js:56 0
PublicPools.js:56 19
PublicPools.js:71 inserted in vistiroes
PublicPools.js:56 25
PublicPools.js:71 inserted in vistiroes
PublicPools.js:56 14
PublicPools.js:71 inserted in vistiroes
PublicPools.js:56 7
PublicPools.js:71 inserted in vistiroes
7PublicPools.js:56 0
PublicPools.js:84 undefined
PublicPools.js:86 undefined
```

useState was working fine there for the moment but started acting weird I tried few solutions but still facing same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setChoices is causing your component to re-render again and again since it's inside a loop, alternatively you can assign the result in temporary variable and then call the setChoices only once after the loop end.

```
const {choices, setChoices} = useState([]);

const getChoices = async () => {
    const temp = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        temp.push({val: i * 2});
    }
    setChoices([...temp]);
}
```

Comment: I wanted my state to be array not single variable how am I supposed to do that?

Comment: yes you can use temporary array, i have edited my response with example to make it clear.